# Add a parameter to display a message if no records returned after executing a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, azure, loops, stored-procedures, not-exists

I am passing a few parameters and getting the respective results for the requested parameter. Suppose I want to add a parameter to display a message if no records are returned after executing a stored procedure - how do I do this?

Comment: Please show us what you have done so far and what you have considered and tried.

Comment: check the value of `@@ROWCOUNT` after your `select` statements to check if records are returned or not, based on that value and then your new input argument, you can `raise` a message[ cannot display image from within stored proc]

Comment: I would posit that the returning some kind of "No records found" message should be a job for the application/presentation layer, not for a stored procedure. Trying to go down the `print`, `raiserror` or `throw` route to do such a thing from a stored procedure just complicates it unnecessarily when the application/presentation layer can simply detect "rowcount = 0" and do the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CASE statement to output the message when no records are found.

Below is the example to return the employees count per City.

Table data which have the employee’s details per City:

[image]

Stored Procedure which gives the count of employees per City and displays a message when no records are found.

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE CheckEmployee_byCity
      @City varchar(100)
 
    AS
    BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    Declare  @ReturnValue Varchar(100);

    SELECT @ReturnValue = case when Count(*)>0 then convert(varchar,count(*)) when count(*)= 0 then 'No Employees found' end
    FROM [dbo].[Employees] WHERE City = @City

    select @ReturnValue as 'Return value'

    END
```

**Result:**

```
EXEC  CheckEmployee_byCity @city = 'London';

EXEC  CheckEmployee_byCity @city = 'California';
```

[image]